# rbind equivalent in revoScaleR

Tags: rbind, revolution-r

how can I concatenate two xdf, as in the rbind function ? 
both xdf have the same names and order of columns .

I saw there is an "append" parameter in the rxImport() function, but I don't get where to specifiy the second xdf file .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities, but one good choice is to use `rxMerge`.  The following will append rows from `xdf2` to `xdf1`. The two input files must have the same number of columns with the same data types.

```
rxMerge(inData = xdf1, inData2 = xdf2, type = "union")
```

Comment: It actually works and is pretty fast with rxImport, need to duplicate xdf1 though

   `rxImport(inData = "xdf2", outFile="xdf1" , append="rows", overwrite = TRUE)`

Comment: As I mentioned, there are multiple possibilities.  `rxMerge`, `rxDataStep`, and `rxImport` are the ones that will carry it out, however, though it can be done with `rxImport` I would say it shouldn't.  The reason is that you are not importing and the spirit of `rxImport` is bringing data into an `XDF`.  It happens that since `rxImport` works on data sources it will work on an `XDF`.  You asked how to concatenate like the `rbind` function, and `rxMerge` is probably closest to the spirit of that function, combined with `cbind` and `merge`.

Comment: got it ! it's not easy to catch the spirit of revo functions at the beginning. 
thanks a lot !